# Facing issue when using bootstrap react table 2

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm new to react and using bootstap react table 2 and getting the following error whenever am adding pagination attribute.

**Uncaught Error: t.render(): A valid React element (or null) must be returned. You may have returned undefined, an array or some other invalid object.**

Can somebody please help?

Following is my code

```
class Users extends Component {
  constructor(){
    super();
     this.state={
     users:[],
     options:{},
    };

  } 

componentDidMount(){

   //code...
}

render() {
  <div className="animated fadeIn">
    return (
                <BootstrapTable keyField="_id" data={ this.state.users } columns={ columns } pagination={ paginationFactory() } />
            );       
  </div>
}
}
```

Comment: In render method you must return a valid structure, in the above code return statement is inside the div, kindly change it to `return (<div className="animated fadeIn">
                <BootstrapTable keyField="_id" data={ this.state.users } columns={ columns } pagination={ paginationFactory() } />
              </div>);`

Comment: event after that am still facing the same issue.